# Offer the ability to enable/disable logging programmatically

Tags: objective-c

I'm building a .Framework and I would like to offer to the developers using my framework the ability to hide or show the NSLogs that are within the framework.

I already use this solution

**Prefix.pch**

```
#ifdef PY_LOGS
#    define PYLog(...) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#    define PYLog(...)
#endif
```

and then use PYLog() in my frameworks so that the developer can set the PY_LOGS flag or not in the preprocessor macros.

It works perfectly but I would like a solution that allows the developer to call something like

```
[[MyFramework sharedInstance] setDebug:YES];
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Look at using a common solution like [LibComponentLogging](http://0xc0.de/LibComponentLogging).

Answer (score 0):

Whats wrong with?

```
#ifdef PY_LOGS
#    define PYLog(...) if([[MyFramework sharedInstance] isLoggingEnabled]){ NSLog(__VA_ARGS__); }
#else
#    define PYLog(...)
#endif
```

Objective-C messaging efficiency is the least of your worries.

Comment: I tried that but I get "Expected ';' after expression" every time I use PYLog().

Comment: and "Use of undeclared identifier 'PirayaSDK'"

Comment: Ok, this version (without braces) gets rid of the ';' error
define PYLog(...) if([[MyFramework sharedInstance] isDebugEnabled]) NSLog(__VA_ARGS__)